# use laravel echo server in react native client

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, laravel-echo

I want to use laravel echo server in react native app
but I think something is wrong that I don't know what is it
I get this error in my log

> > undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.connector.channel')
> >     channel
> >         D:\react-native\taav\node_modules\laravel-echo\dist\echo.js:750:34
> >     componentDidMount

it is my laravel

```
class updateStatus implements  ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public $activity;
public function __construct( Activity $a)
{
    //

    $this->activity=$a;

}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return ['channel'];
}

}
```

that I know my laravel server is correct because I can use correctly my socket in browser

and my react native code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

 import Echo from "laravel-echo"
  import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';

 export default class Activities extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.btnadd = this.btnadd.bind(this)
    this.SearchMethod = this.SearchMethod.bind(this)
    this.socket = io('http://'.concat(server).concat(':6001'), {json: false})

}
 componentDidMount() {


    var echo = window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: 'io',
        host: 'http://'.concat(server).concat(':6001')
    });

    window.Echo.channel('channel')
        .listen('updateStatus', (e) => {
            // this.additem()

        })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try defining your broadcaster as 'socket.io' instead and that error should go away:

```
var echo = window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://'.concat(server).concat(':6001')
});
```

Edit:
Looks like I'd also done some more magic with the echo library. From memory there was an issue getting the Echo library to pickup 'io' when it's imported here. What I ended up doing was copying the Echo code directly into my project and editing it to make it work. If you copy echo.js from /node_modules/laravel-echo/dist/echo.js into your own project and add this to the start of the file:

```
window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native';
var io = require('socket.io-client');
```

and this to the end of the file:

```
export default Echo;
```

Then find the line of code that says

```
this.socket = io(this.options.host, {...this.options, ...{jsonp: false}});
```

and replace it with the following:

```
this.socket = io(this.options.host, this.options);
```

Then in your code above import Echo from this version in your project instead of from laravel-echo you'll hopefully have better luck. Sorry I didn't remember about that to start with!